# no suitable method found .put(String)

Tags: java, methods, symbols, bluej

Hi there I am a first year uni student and am new to java,
we are making a hotel system where a room can have newspaper(s) added to them and you can assign people to a room and I am having an error in this part of my code.

```
   public void addPapers (String roomNo, String paper) {

        if(isValidNo(roomNo)) {
            for(Room room: occupiedRooms) {
                if (room.getRoomNo().equals(roomNo)) {
                    room.addPapers(paper);
                    PapersOrdered.put(roomNo, room.getPapers());
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

the .put comes with an error saying no suitable method found for put javalang java lang String
I take out the .getpapers method in my other class that i get it from and the error goes however I then get a error on could not find symbol method.

Any Advice would be great 
P.S sorry I am new to all of this.

Comment: what's the method definition of your method PapersOrdered.put?

Comment: The method is public HashMap PapersOrdered()
    {
        return PapersOrdered; 

    }

Comment: I'd be helpful if you post a more complete fragment of code.

Comment: private HashSet<Room>occupiedRooms;
    private HashMap <String,ArrayList<String>> PapersOrdered = new   HashMap <String,ArrayList<String>>();


    public Hotel()
    {
        occupiedRooms = new HashSet<Room>();
        PapersOrdered = new HashMap <String,ArrayList<String>>();

    }

   here is the field and also the start of the hotel class if this is any help.

Comment: roomNo must be a String and the return type of room.getPapers() must be ArrayList<String> for the put method to work, are you sure that is the case?

Comment: I am sure as that is what my lecturer told me to put but I'm finding it hard to get my head around

Comment: Sorry if I am so unclear

Answer (score 0):

```
PapersOrdered.put(roomNo, room.getPapers());
```

It appears that you are calling an *instance* method (`put`) on a class. Where is `PapersOrdered` defined? Is it a type or a field? It isn't declared in `addPapers`.

Comment: i have a method which is public HashMap PapersOrdered()
    {
        return PapersOrdered; 

    }

I put import java.util.HashMap in also